# angular.copy() does not work inside angular brackets {{}}

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using "as vm" syntax inside a controller. I use angular.copy() to copy one data structure into a temporary one.

```
angular.copy(vm.data, vm.tempData = [])
```

However, I want to move this code into the template view so I don't have to rely on a controller function call. This is because when I rewrite the code, I don't need to rewrite the code in the controller as well.

```
{{vm.temp = []}}                          //works
{{vm.temp = vm.data}}                     //works
{{vm.temp = angular.copy([])}}            //does not work
{{vm.temp = angular.copy(vm.data)}}       //does not work, I need this or
{{angular.copy(vm.data, vm.temp = [])}}   //does not work, I need this
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to copy something inside string interpolation which is wrong, you need to provide your full code like which event fires the copy

Comment: Why would you ever need to do anything like this in the view? Business like this belongs in a controller

Comment: The business is conveniently inside angular.copy. I want to access angular.copy with {{}} or ng-init, but can't.

Comment: but why - it sounds like a code smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic should be done in the controller, that's what the controller is for. But to answer your question, from the [angular docs on expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

> **Context**: JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global
>   window. In AngularJS, expressions are evaluated against a scope object

This means it's trying to look for the `angular` definition under the `$scope` object in your expression. So to do what you want, you would have to do this in the controller:

```
$scope.angular = angular;
```

Comment: It's spitting out a long error message: Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22[...]    
    
Looks like its caused by a ng-repeat further down. It seems the angular.copy successfully copied though.

Answer (score 0):

my workaround: create a wrapper function

```
vm.copy = function (item1, item2) {
    return angular.copy(item1, item2);
};
```

then call it inside your html with ng-init, not with {{ }}

```
ng-init="vm.copy(vm.data, vm.tempData = [])"
```